# Fail to create subscription on reconnected opcua milo client

Tags: java, opc-ua, reconnect, milo

Milo client v0.5.2 (same with current v0.6.8) is connected to the opcua server, I restart the server and the milo client reconnects successfully but the subscriptions are lost, so I'm attempting to recreate them by `onSessionActive` listener.

I even do a `getSubscriptionManager().clearSubscriptions()` before `getSubscriptionManager().createSubscription(scanRate)`. The `createSubscription` method ends up with a null `Future`. So it does not even give an exception, the code execution seems to stop and not return from there and so the invocation to recreate the monitoring subscriptions won't work.

`onTransferFailed` occures multiple times and I would reestablish the subscriptions for all, so it would be more convenient to call at onSessionActive which is after the onSubscriptionTransferFailed events. Anyway the `client.getSubscriptionManager().createSubscription(scanRate)` behaves the same way when calling at `onSubscriptionTransferFailed`: the code execution doesn't return and subscriptions are not made. This is triggered in the first onSubscriptionTransferFailed and no subsequent onSubscriptionTransferFailed events are occuring.

If providing some values of the milo client at onSubscriptionTransferFailed or other point, I could help to better grasp the issue.

My main issue is this full reconnection where the subscriptions are lost and has to be reestablished.
There is no way to reinitialize the failed subscription monitors without recreating the subscriptions but that seems to break the Milo client's FSM machinery.

How to go about this problem now?

Answer (score 0):

You should be re-creating them in the `SubscriptionListener::onSubscripionTransferFailed` callback.

Comment: `onTransferFailed` occures multiple times and I would rerun the subscriptions for all, so it would be more convenient to call at `onSessionActive` which is after the `onSubscriptionTransferFailed` events. Anyway the `client.getSubscriptionManager().createSubscription(scanRate).get()` behaves the same way, even when calling at `onSubscriptionTransferFailed` the code execution doesn't return and subscriptions are not made. This is triggered in the first `onSubscriptionTransferFailed` and no subsequent `onSubscriptionTransferFailed` events are occuring this way...

Comment: It occurs once for each subscription that failed to transfer, indicated by the `subscription` argument it receives.

Comment: It _should_ be safe to make a blocking call that requires the session inside `onSubscriptionTransferFailed`, but I'm not sure if it's safe in the other callbacks.

Comment: Stucks with `client.getSubscriptionManager().createSubscription(scanRate).get()` at `onSubscriptionTransferFailed` as well, so have no idea how to workaround this resubscription issue. Is there a generic call to reinitialize the failed subscription monitors without `getSubscriptionManager().createSubscription(scanRate).get()` in it?

Comment: If providing some values of the milo client at `onSubscriptionTransferFailed` would help to grasp the issue, feel free to ask for them and I will extend the question.

Comment: @obeliksz I modified one of the subscription examples to show it works. You must have something in one of your callbacks blocking the completion of the SessionFsm machinery. I connected it to the demo server running locally, then restarted the demo server and observed the subscription re-created and the updates resume. https://gist.github.com/kevinherron/dcc78798befa71b3cdc137cbbc61a456

Comment: Thank you. Could you give any hints what could be blocking the SessionFsm? Details on the SessionFsm machinery? It is true, that before this createSubscription call we do have some operations to be completed beforehand to get the list of items that should be monitored. Could we call something before or encolse our fetching code into some kind of block inside the onSubscriptionTransferFailed that prevents the blocking of SessionFsm machinery?

Comment: I would guess the problem is in some other callback like `onSessionInactive` or `onSessionActive` maybe? `onSubscriptionTransferFailed` gets called on a thread pool, so you won’t block the FSM, you would only potentially just not get to the create call - have you debugged and verified you get there or stepped through your logic in the `onSubscriptionTransferFailed` callback?

Comment: Probably the problem is that I'm not getting to the create call, getting a null Future. As soon as the first createSubscription is called the execution is not comleted and code execution doesnt resume, also there will be no more subsequent TransferFailed events catched. There are no other calls in the onSessionActive/onSessionInactive listeners, only setting a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience only having a clear milo opcua client enables the creation of a new subscription after a full disconnect. After `onSubscriptionTransferFailed` that is detecting any subscription loss its safe to assume that the server is back online.

The subscriptions have to be re-created always after a full disconnect.

Have tried switching to the higher level `ManagedSubscription`, but that doesn't solve this full disconnect-reconnect resubscription issue as it was already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41891640/opc-ua-server-reboot-and-subscriptions/41895509#41895509):

```
OPC UA 1.03 did introduce the concept of durable subscriptions, which are supposed to be able to save state and survive restarts, but I don't know of any servers that implement this right now.
```